# Excel - Copy Row to Another Sheet Based on Data Match

Tags: excel, copy, row

I have looked at similar questions but they don't seem to fit my problem. I have two sheets in excel; one has a type of header/overview data for some tasks, the other has several lines of details for each task.

I need help writing a macro that will match the Task ID between the two sheets and copy the entire row of header data from sheet one into a blank row  above the group of detail rows in sheet two.

(Before this code will run, I will run a macro that will insert a blank line between each group of detail data. When I get this working, I will combine the two pieces of code.)

The copy statement is where I am stuck. It returns Application defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub InsertMWITitles()
‘copies the MWI titles above the correct MWI Steps group

Dim lngLastRowSht1, lngLastRowSht2, counterSht1, counterSht2As Long


With Worksheets(“MWI Titles”)
    lngLastRowSht1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    lngLastRowSht2 = Worksheets(“MWI Steps”).Cells(Worksheets(“MWI Steps”).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For counterSht1 = 1 To lngLastRowSht1
            For counterSht2 = 1 To lngLastRowSht2

    ‘if the Task ID in column H of the MWI Titles sheet matches the Element ID in column A of 
    ‘the MWI Steps sheet, copy the entire title row to the steps sheet above the group
    
                If Worksheets(“MWI Titles”).Range("H" & (counterSht1)).Value = Sheets(2).Range("A" & counterSht2).Value Then
                    Worksheets(“MWI Titles”).Range("A" & (counterSht2).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(“MWI Steps”).Range("A" & (counterSht2 – 1))
                End If
            Next counterSht2
        Next counterSht1
End With
End Sub
```

I also tried to copy and insert with shift down, but couldn't get that to work either.

The top section of the sample data is sheet 1/MWI Titles (the header data) and the bottom section is sheet 2 /MWI Steps (the detail data).
[Sample of data in both sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrT94.gif)

Comment: What your screen print doesn't show us is which is sheet 1 and which is sheet 2 and which data you want copied from sheet 2 to sheet 1? Also, please provide the code that you have so far so we can help you build the code

Comment: Sorry, I thought the different header rows made the two sheets obvious; the top section is sheet one. When the Task ID on sheet one matches sheet two, I need to copy the entire row for that task in the blank row that was inserted above that task group to create a header of sorts for each group. I don't have any code so far, except for the code that inserts the blank line when the task ID changes.